# Изменить метод findByOneCss чтобы он получал не одно значение а все

Tags: java, c#, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver

Вот сам метод

```
private static  WebElement findByOneCss(WebElement we, String selector) {
    try {
        return we.findElement(By.cssSelector(selector));
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Понимаю, что `findElement` нужно поменять на `findElements` но как не понимаю приму к вниманию все мнения.

Не получается продолжить у меня есть цикл который обходит значения вот он

```
    for (WebElement wle : wlElements) {
    WebElement commenWe = findByOneCss(wle, ".activity-new-val");
    wl.setReason1(commenWe != null ? commenWe.getText() : "");
    wlList.add(wl);
```

Что в нем надо изменить я пробовал вот так

```
    List<WebElement> commenWe = findAllByOneCss(wle, ".activity-old-val");
    wl.setReason(commenWe != null ? ((WebElement) commenWe).getText():"");
    wlList.add(wl);
```

Но оно выбивает ошибку java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement

Answer (score 1):

```
private static  List<WebElement> findAllByOneCss(WebElement we, String selector) {
    try {
        return we.findElements(By.cssSelector(selector));
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```